# Newton Raphson does not converge with certain initial guess

Tags: fortran

```
 program newton_raphson
    implicit none
    real,parameter::error=1e-4
    integer::i
    real::xo,x1,f,fd
    print*,"Please enter the initial guess !!!"
    read*,xo
    i=1
    10 x1=xo-(f(xo)/fd(xo))
    if(abs((x1-xo)/x1)<error) then
    print*,"root is", x1,"no. of iteration=",i
    else
    xo=x1
    i=i+1
    goto 10
    endif
    end

    real function f(x)
    real::x
    f=cos(x)
    end

    real function fd(x)
    real::x
    fd=-sin(x)

    end
```

This program works fine when I give 1 as an initial guess, but fails or doesn't show up anything when I give 0 as an initial guess. Is there any mistake with my code.

Comment: The manner in which it fails is important.  If you have a question about that, though, please show the error message and what expectations you have about behaviour.  It's more likely that you have a mathematical question than a computing one, that said: what do you expect to happen to when `f(0)/fd(0)` is evaluated?

Comment: Arghh.........Sorry, Thanks for clarifying....

Answer (score 3):

Although the Newton–Raphson method converges fast near the root, its global
convergence characteristics are poor. The reason is that the tangent line is not always an acceptable approximation of the function, so could try to combine your code with bisection method, and this way you can improve the results.